# Extracting data tables from HTML source after scraping using Selenium & Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this [link](http://www.scstrade.com/MarketStatistics/MS_HistoricalIndices.aspx). I've researched on question that are asked and I've successfully did some scraping. But I've few issues in results that are generated. Following is the piece of code that I've used to scrape.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options() 
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.scstrade.com/MarketStatistics/MS_HistoricalIndices.aspx') 

inputElement_index = driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearch")
inputElement_index.send_keys('KSE ALL')


inputElement_date = driver.find_element_by_id("date1")
inputElement_date.send_keys('03/12/2019')

inputElement_date_end = driver.find_element_by_id("date2")
inputElement_date_end.send_keys('03/12/2020')

inputElement_viewprice = driver.find_element_by_id("btn1")
inputElement_viewprice.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

tabel = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table > tbody')[0]
```

Aim is to extract data from the [link](http://www.scstrade.com/MarketStatistics/MS_HistoricalIndices.aspx) with dates between 12th Mar 2020 to 03rd Mar 2020, with indices `KSE ALL`. Now the above code works but in the last line of the code table object is blank when the code runs for the first time if I re-run this last line it gives the table in string format that is on the 1st page. **I want to know why don't I get the table when the code runs for the first time? How can I get a pandas DataFrame for the table object which is in string?**

I tried the following code to get 1st page data into pandas DataFrame. But the table object turns out to be `'NoneType'`.

```
htmlSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_='tbody')
```

Second, I want to extract entire data, not just the data on first page and number of pages would be dynamic they would change as date range changes. Now to move to next page I tried the following piece of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("next_pager").click()
```

I got the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <td id="next_pager" class="ui-pg-button" title="Next Page">...</td> is not clickable at point (790, 95). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading row" id="load_list" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

I tried to look up on how can this issue be resolved wrote the code below to add some waiting time. But got the same error as above.

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[title="Next Page"]'))).click()
```

**How can I move to subsequent pages and extract data from all pages (no. of pages would be dynamic as per the date range set) and append it to data extracted from the previous page?**

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer using the api approach in this case, it would be faster and easy to get the data. And also you don't have to load number of pages in the table.
Below is the API code to get the response code (just changed the date range to make sure you will see multiple pages data in one request call)

```
import requests

url = "http://www.scstrade.com/MarketStatistics/MS_HistoricalIndices.aspx/chart"

payload = "{\"par\": \"KSE All\", \"date1\": \"01/03/2020\",\"date2\": \"03/12/2020\"}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

The only thing is you have to change the date format in the response.

**result:**

```
b'{"d":[{"kse_index_id":13362,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1577991600000)\\/","kse_index_open":30046.67,"kse_index_high":30053.64,"kse_index_low":29665.65,"kse_index_close":29774.00,"kse_index_value":322398592,"kse_index_change":-98.97,"kse_index_changep":-0.33},{"kse_index_id":13366,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578250800000)\\/","kse_index_open":29547.06,"kse_index_high":29774.00,"kse_index_low":29101.65,"kse_index_close":29145.52,"kse_index_value":266525664,"kse_index_change":-628.48,"kse_index_changep":-2.11},{"kse_index_id":13370,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578337200000)\\/","kse_index_open":29209.91,"kse_index_high":29393.74,"kse_index_low":29072.69,"kse_index_close":29375.75,"kse_index_value":206397936,"kse_index_change":230.23,"kse_index_changep":0.79},{"kse_index_id":13374,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578423600000)\\/","kse_index_open":29157.77,"kse_index_high":29375.75,"kse_index_low":28882.75,"kse_index_close":29010.85,"kse_index_value":279807072,"kse_index_change":-364.90,"kse_index_changep":-1.24},{"kse_index_id":13378,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578510000000)\\/","kse_index_open":29319.08,"kse_index_high":29667.92,"kse_index_low":29010.85,"kse_index_close":29654.66,"kse_index_value":361992128,"kse_index_change":643.81,"kse_index_changep":2.22},{"kse_index_id":13382,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578596400000)\\/","kse_index_open":29732.02,"kse_index_high":30070.99,"kse_index_low":29654.66,"kse_index_close":30058.45,"kse_index_value":400051936,"kse_index_change":403.79,"kse_index_changep":1.36},{"kse_index_id":13386,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578855600000)\\/","kse_index_open":30109.26,"kse_index_high":30194.74,"kse_index_low":29901.75,"kse_index_close":30020.98,"kse_index_value":365810592,"kse_index_change":-37.47,"kse_index_changep":-0.13},{"kse_index_id":13390,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1578942000000)\\/","kse_index_open":30059.23,"kse_index_high":30150.96,"kse_index_low":29932.22,"kse_index_close":29973.44,"kse_index_value":249556960,"kse_index_change":-47.54,"kse_index_changep":-0.16},{"kse_index_id":13394,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579028400000)\\/","kse_index_open":29986.93,"kse_index_high":29999.17,"kse_index_low":29799.04,"kse_index_close":29892.79,"kse_index_value":171127728,"kse_index_change":-80.65,"kse_index_changep":-0.27},{"kse_index_id":13398,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579114800000)\\/","kse_index_open":29913.22,"kse_index_high":30007.53,"kse_index_low":29779.46,"kse_index_close":29914.47,"kse_index_value":229585632,"kse_index_change":21.68,"kse_index_changep":0.07},{"kse_index_id":13402,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579201200000)\\/","kse_index_open":29929.81,"kse_index_high":30037.83,"kse_index_low":29914.46,"kse_index_close":29998.45,"kse_index_value":211220464,"kse_index_change":83.98,"kse_index_changep":0.28},{"kse_index_id":13406,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579460400000)\\/","kse_index_open":30043.65,"kse_index_high":30089.73,"kse_index_low":29734.95,"kse_index_close":29808.60,"kse_index_value":173774336,"kse_index_change":-189.85,"kse_index_changep":-0.63},{"kse_index_id":13410,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579546800000)\\/","kse_index_open":29856.28,"kse_index_high":29928.72,"kse_index_low":29621.78,"kse_index_close":29735.95,"kse_index_value":177421264,"kse_index_change":-72.65,"kse_index_changep":-0.24},{"kse_index_id":13414,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579633200000)\\/","kse_index_open":29746.05,"kse_index_high":29754.25,"kse_index_low":29308.76,"kse_index_close":29561.63,"kse_index_value":177486256,"kse_index_change":-174.32,"kse_index_changep":-0.59},{"kse_index_id":13418,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579719600000)\\/","kse_index_open":29621.60,"kse_index_high":29759.68,"kse_index_low":29409.24,"kse_index_close":29456.52,"kse_index_value":230561152,"kse_index_change":-105.11,"kse_index_changep":-0.36},{"kse_index_id":13422,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1579806000000)\\/","kse_index_open":29440.00,"kse_index_high":29585.39,"kse_index_low":29318.90,"kse_index_close":29529.89,"kse_index_value":172677024,"kse_index_change":73.37,"kse_index_changep":0.25},{"kse_index_id":13426,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580065200000)\\/","kse_index_open":29533.27,"kse_index_high":29594.55,"kse_index_low":29431.95,"kse_index_close":29462.60,"kse_index_value":198224992,"kse_index_change":-67.29,"kse_index_changep":-0.23},{"kse_index_id":13430,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580151600000)\\/","kse_index_open":29457.47,"kse_index_high":29462.59,"kse_index_low":29230.53,"kse_index_close":29345.90,"kse_index_value":188781760,"kse_index_change":-116.70,"kse_index_changep":-0.40},{"kse_index_id":13434,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580238000000)\\/","kse_index_open":29354.64,"kse_index_high":29446.90,"kse_index_low":29083.61,"kse_index_close":29135.35,"kse_index_value":197011200,"kse_index_change":-210.55,"kse_index_changep":-0.72},{"kse_index_id":13438,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580324400000)\\/","kse_index_open":29132.60,"kse_index_high":29181.59,"kse_index_low":28969.60,"kse_index_close":29123.53,"kse_index_value":162120016,"kse_index_change":-11.82,"kse_index_changep":-0.04},{"kse_index_id":13442,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580410800000)\\/","kse_index_open":29166.18,"kse_index_high":29257.79,"kse_index_low":28945.19,"kse_index_close":29067.54,"kse_index_value":193415040,"kse_index_change":-55.99,"kse_index_changep":-0.19},{"kse_index_id":13446,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580670000000)\\/","kse_index_open":28941.02,"kse_index_high":29067.54,"kse_index_low":28246.97,"kse_index_close":28315.61,"kse_index_value":202691712,"kse_index_change":-751.93,"kse_index_changep":-2.59},{"kse_index_id":13450,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580756400000)\\/","kse_index_open":28356.76,"kse_index_high":28506.86,"kse_index_low":28245.23,"kse_index_close":28493.84,"kse_index_value":145986304,"kse_index_change":178.23,"kse_index_changep":0.63},{"kse_index_id":13454,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1580929200000)\\/","kse_index_open":28577.12,"kse_index_high":28633.74,"kse_index_low":28375.60,"kse_index_close":28398.38,"kse_index_value":127719744,"kse_index_change":-95.46,"kse_index_changep":-0.34},{"kse_index_id":13458,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581015600000)\\/","kse_index_open":28458.74,"kse_index_high":28458.75,"kse_index_low":27983.62,"kse_index_close":28042.82,"kse_index_value":193151648,"kse_index_change":-355.56,"kse_index_changep":-1.25},{"kse_index_id":13462,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581274800000)\\/","kse_index_open":28043.58,"kse_index_high":28053.71,"kse_index_low":27470.38,"kse_index_close":27520.35,"kse_index_value":180630816,"kse_index_change":-522.47,"kse_index_changep":-1.86},{"kse_index_id":13466,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581361200000)\\/","kse_index_open":27601.00,"kse_index_high":28017.17,"kse_index_low":27492.28,"kse_index_close":27865.16,"kse_index_value":161458304,"kse_index_change":344.81,"kse_index_changep":1.25},{"kse_index_id":13470,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581447600000)\\/","kse_index_open":27959.20,"kse_index_high":28384.45,"kse_index_low":27865.16,"kse_index_close":28309.35,"kse_index_value":179861264,"kse_index_change":444.19,"kse_index_changep":1.59},{"kse_index_id":13474,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581534000000)\\/","kse_index_open":28380.58,"kse_index_high":28468.96,"kse_index_low":28191.97,"kse_index_close":28256.09,"kse_index_value":197307008,"kse_index_change":-53.26,"kse_index_changep":-0.19},{"kse_index_id":13478,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581620400000)\\/","kse_index_open":28327.55,"kse_index_high":28330.57,"kse_index_low":27917.81,"kse_index_close":28015.75,"kse_index_value":117521904,"kse_index_change":-240.34,"kse_index_changep":-0.85},{"kse_index_id":13482,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581879600000)\\/","kse_index_open":28023.74,"kse_index_high":28130.89,"kse_index_low":27900.27,"kse_index_close":28002.69,"kse_index_value":99813272,"kse_index_change":-13.06,"kse_index_changep":-0.05},{"kse_index_id":13486,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1581966000000)\\/","kse_index_open":28036.95,"kse_index_high":28141.44,"kse_index_low":27758.54,"kse_index_close":27807.10,"kse_index_value":91269288,"kse_index_change":-195.59,"kse_index_changep":-0.70},{"kse_index_id":13490,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582052400000)\\/","kse_index_open":27843.99,"kse_index_high":28108.02,"kse_index_low":27807.11,"kse_index_close":28063.85,"kse_index_value":142765888,"kse_index_change":256.75,"kse_index_changep":0.92},{"kse_index_id":13494,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582138800000)\\/","kse_index_open":28122.04,"kse_index_high":28132.98,"kse_index_low":27989.14,"kse_index_close":28018.02,"kse_index_value":111998784,"kse_index_change":-45.83,"kse_index_changep":-0.16},{"kse_index_id":13498,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582225200000)\\/","kse_index_open":28028.61,"kse_index_high":28039.38,"kse_index_low":27856.26,"kse_index_close":27895.15,"kse_index_value":85454400,"kse_index_change":-122.87,"kse_index_changep":-0.44},{"kse_index_id":13502,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582484400000)\\/","kse_index_open":27880.35,"kse_index_high":27895.15,"kse_index_low":27200.92,"kse_index_close":27248.30,"kse_index_value":144128160,"kse_index_change":-646.85,"kse_index_changep":-2.32},{"kse_index_id":13506,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582570800000)\\/","kse_index_open":27206.95,"kse_index_high":27321.33,"kse_index_low":26851.06,"kse_index_close":27018.98,"kse_index_value":124276016,"kse_index_change":-229.32,"kse_index_changep":-0.84},{"kse_index_id":13510,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582657200000)\\/","kse_index_open":27058.85,"kse_index_high":27070.75,"kse_index_low":26560.92,"kse_index_close":26687.95,"kse_index_value":147798160,"kse_index_change":-331.03,"kse_index_changep":-1.23},{"kse_index_id":13514,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582743600000)\\/","kse_index_open":26355.50,"kse_index_high":26687.95,"kse_index_low":25780.38,"kse_index_close":26396.96,"kse_index_value":248988672,"kse_index_change":-290.99,"kse_index_changep":-1.09},{"kse_index_id":13518,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1582830000000)\\/","kse_index_open":26302.05,"kse_index_high":26519.47,"kse_index_low":26181.00,"kse_index_close":26289.38,"kse_index_value":201662240,"kse_index_change":-107.58,"kse_index_changep":-0.41},{"kse_index_id":13522,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583089200000)\\/","kse_index_open":26342.71,"kse_index_high":27096.59,"kse_index_low":26289.38,"kse_index_close":27059.34,"kse_index_value":215058320,"kse_index_change":769.96,"kse_index_changep":2.93},{"kse_index_id":13526,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583175600000)\\/","kse_index_open":27200.11,"kse_index_high":27385.30,"kse_index_low":26854.16,"kse_index_close":27054.89,"kse_index_value":225222304,"kse_index_change":-4.45,"kse_index_changep":-0.02},{"kse_index_id":13530,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583262000000)\\/","kse_index_open":27070.16,"kse_index_high":27069.35,"kse_index_low":26797.32,"kse_index_close":26919.79,"kse_index_value":186877760,"kse_index_change":-135.10,"kse_index_changep":-0.50},{"kse_index_id":13534,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583348400000)\\/","kse_index_open":26961.15,"kse_index_high":27369.98,"kse_index_low":26919.79,"kse_index_close":27228.79,"kse_index_value":340043072,"kse_index_change":309.00,"kse_index_changep":1.15},{"kse_index_id":13538,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583434800000)\\/","kse_index_open":27126.48,"kse_index_high":27228.79,"kse_index_low":26517.64,"kse_index_close":26557.85,"kse_index_value":244063824,"kse_index_change":-670.94,"kse_index_changep":-2.46},{"kse_index_id":13542,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583694000000)\\/","kse_index_open":25878.94,"kse_index_high":26557.85,"kse_index_low":25304.60,"kse_index_close":25875.06,"kse_index_value":307753952,"kse_index_change":-682.79,"kse_index_changep":-2.57},{"kse_index_id":13546,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583780400000)\\/","kse_index_open":25758.62,"kse_index_high":26210.06,"kse_index_low":25719.55,"kse_index_close":26184.13,"kse_index_value":274065504,"kse_index_change":309.07,"kse_index_changep":1.19},{"kse_index_id":13550,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583866800000)\\/","kse_index_open":26331.02,"kse_index_high":26562.31,"kse_index_low":26061.81,"kse_index_close":26127.67,"kse_index_value":217595296,"kse_index_change":-56.46,"kse_index_changep":-0.22},{"kse_index_id":13554,"kse_index_type_id":1,"kse_index_date":"\\/Date(1583953200000)\\/","kse_index_open":26002.00,"kse_index_high":26127.67,"kse_index_low":25245.98,"kse_index_close":25310.97,"kse_index_value":230028032,"kse_index_change":-816.70,"kse_index_changep":-3.13}]}'
```

Comment: how can I get response in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I've used `t.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %p', t.localtime(1577991600))` to convert change date format. len of input unix time should be 10 so I've removed zeroes from the end to make len equal 10