# VBA web scraping: Difference between internet explorer and XMLHTTP request

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am learning web scraping in VBA. And i am unable to understand the difference in results of requests sent through internet Explorer and XMLHTTP request.

This is the website -- http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotQF.aspx?symbol=LUCK

Scraping through IE writes perfect results in the text file but XMLHTTP request writes empty string in the text file. I can not understand the reason. The code for each method is given below:

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim page As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim st As Scripting.TextStream
   
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotQF.aspx?symbol=DGKC"

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set ele = ie.document.getElementById("listisq1")

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set st = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myFile.txt")
st.Write ele.innerText
```

And the code for XMLHTTP request is as follows

```
Dim page As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim st As Scripting.TextStream

req.Open "GET", "http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotQF.aspx?symbol=LUCK", False
req.send

If req.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "req failed"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set page = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

page.body.innerHTML = req.responseText

Set ele = page.getElementById("listisq1")

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set st = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\XMLHTTPscrape.txt")
st.Write ele.innerText
```

And this method (XMLHTTP) is writing nothing in the text file. Please guide me if there is something wrong with the code or is there an inherent difference in the two methods. Thanks

Comment: You can't grab content from that site using `xmlhttp` requests by sending `get` http requests as the content in there is javascript heavy. However, if you send `post` http requests with appropriate parameters, you can parse the content from json response.

Comment: Can u share an example code OR can you point to a source that can help me learn how to get javascript content

Comment: Seems like there is an [Api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663688/9439330), you can use (maybe you need an account). You read the terms of use/service to check if scraping isn't forbidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following should give you the content of [this portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXAbY.jpg) in json response.

```
Sub GetContent()
    Const link = "http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotQF.aspx/isq4"
    Dim payload As Variant

    payload = "{'sym':'LUCK','_search':false,'nd':1600525542589,'rows':30,'page':1,'sidx':'Year / Quarter','sord':'desc'}"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", link, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send payload
        MsgBox .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to send few post requests to get the whole content by the way.

Comment: Outstanding. Splendid. It is working perfectly. Just one more question. A lot of people advised me to use selenium or web browser. But if you can do it in VBA in XMLHTTP then why go for some other options. Question is that: Can we scrape all types of data from websites without Selenium or Is there a point where there is no option left but to shift to selenium? (For VBA developers)

Comment: Yes, you can scrape most of the times using xmlhttp requests. However, there are some occasion when it's really hard to send post requests or find any undocumented api or script tag to process the content. In such cases you should go for IE or selenium. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. If I need further help from you, is there a forum where i can contact you directly?

Comment: With the sun setting of IE next month, will XMLHTTP still work?